# Remove -j 4 when building with Visual Studio Code's CMake Tools extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

When I use CMake Tools extension to build a project or all projects in Visual Studio Code, it always adds `-- -j 4` to build command:

```
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/tc/MyProject/build --config Release --target all -- -j 4
```

How do I remove it? I think it belongs to the CMake Tools extension configuration but I don't know where it is.

Comment: There are several configurable options under **Settings** > **Extensions** > **CMake Tools configuration**. If you can't find it in there, you may be able to find it in one of the `.json` settings files.

Answer (score 6):

Using `Visual Studio Code 1.47.3` and `CMake Tools 1.4.1`:

1. Go to the settings page.
2. Search for "parallel".
3. Look for the item titled "CMake: Parallel Jobs".

The default for this setting appears to be 0, which presumably causes the tool to determine the `-j` argument dynamically.

4. Select the scope (e.g., User, Workspace, etc.) in which you want to customize the setting.
5. Change the value to whatever whole number you prefer--1 to disable parallel build tasks.

Comment: I realize that this doesn't answer the exact question, which asks how to _eliminate_ the `-j` option. These steps describe how to change the value used for the option so that the build uses no parallelization.